# ActiveDirectoryServerDownException when getting the current Domain on a Wireless network

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a problem regarding the Active Directory classes in C#. At one moment in my program, I am trying to get the current Domain the user is logged in using the following command:

```
Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
```

Most of the times, it works. But when executing from a wireless laptop, it gives me the following error:

```
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryServerDownException: The server is not operational.

    Name: "DOMAIN.ca"
     ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The server is not operational.

       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
       at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
       at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList()
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.PropertyManager.GetPropertyValue(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, String propertyName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.PropertyManager.GetPropertyValue(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, String propertyName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(DirectoryContext context)
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain()
   at ADT.ADTools.ComputerIsInDomain()
```

In my particular case, this piece of code should work on any account logged in an Active Directory account, regardless of the computer it's being ran on or if the computer is connected to the domain using wireless or wired connection.

Does anyone of you knows the answer to that problem or any workarounds I could do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The source of the problem was internal to our business network. I did a couple of things :

- Set up a third DNS address on the main router that points to the AD DNS server.
- On the wireless network card, put as the Prefered DNS server the IP of the AD DNS server and as the Alternative DNS server, the IP of the main router.

Comment: People adding a secondary DNS controller, like Google's 8.8.8.8 server, thinking it will help, are incredibly frustrating as it causes all sorts of grief with AD-based authentication, domain controller lookups, etc.  Just let your internal DNS server handle the work.  It can forward on requests to an external server and even cache results for use of other PCs on the network.  Win-win.