# Domain.GetCurrentDomain() returns different values randomly

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

From a computer that I've logged into using a domain account, Domain.GetCurrentDomain() will occasionally return false for no specific reason. Then, seemingly minutes later, it'll return true again as it should.

Why is this method so unreliable and how can I go about diagnosing / fixing this issue?

Comment: [`Domain.GetCurrentDomain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getcurrentdomain.aspx) doesn't return a `bool`. Are you sure that is the method you are calling?

Comment: You're right, it instead throws a variety of exceptions which we catch. However the point still stands that it will occasionally throw the exception, and other times won't. Seemingly random from minute to minute even.

Comment: It throws: `ActiveDirectoryServerDownException: The server is not operational` which is evidently false as I had just logged into the domain using my domain account. Am I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347638/activedirectoryserverdownexception-when-getting-the-current-domain-on-a-wireless) is of help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had tried that at first before creating this question. Thanks for the help though!